# Java Base64 and Android base64

Tags: java, android, web-services

I'm trying to access a Java WebService,

I'm using Android `Base64(Base64.encodeToString(byte[], Base64.DEFAULT))` encode byte array. but the Java WebService can't resolve it.

I get the following error:

```
11-30 20:41:39.008: I/System.out(25297): error in opening zip file
```

JDK Base64Encoder and Android Base64 has different?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the `android.*` namespace is available in standard Java. Use the `Base64Encoder` instead. If you are having compatibility problems, you might use a standalone codec like [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

Answer (score 0):

in the webservice, try using javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter. It has static methods that make this easy.

for decode :

```
DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary()
```

and for encode :

```
DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary()
```